# What method can I use to update the state on repeated action?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I need to use updated data from the local storage, but with this method, the state is not updated but supplemented. What are the alternatives?

```
export const contactList = [];

export function getContacts(state = contactList, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOAD_CONTACTS_FROM_STORAGE':
      for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length - 1; i++) {
        state.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(`contact${i}`)))
      }
      let newState = [];
      newState = state;
      console.log(newState);

      return [...state];
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Let's see, you push on the state, thus mutating it, then create a newState as an empty array, but then set newState to be state after which you are creating a shallow copy of the original (already mutated) state...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not mutate the state directly. If you want to add new storage items to state, just save them to new array and add it to state. If you want to replace the state with the storage items, return the storage items array instead.

```
export const contactList = [];

export function getContacts(state = contactList, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOAD_CONTACTS_FROM_STORAGE':
      let storageItems = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length - 1; i++) {
        storageItems.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(`contact${i}`)))
      }
      return [...state, ...storageItems];  // Or return storageItems; if you want to replace the state
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: I had to create a new action for this, but on your advice. Thanks, it helped.